# Rename it after copied using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to recursively copy the files and rename them.

My folders has file with same name ,so i need to rename it the moment it is copied.

But i am keep facing issue. Following is my code. It should find the CopyForBuild.bat file and copy it to E:\CopyForBuild folder. Once it is copied , the first file should be Copyforbuild1.txt , the second one will be CopyforBuild2.txt and so on.

Following is my code. Where am i failing?

```
$File = Get-ChildItem -Path V:\MyFolder -Filter CopyForbuild.bat -Recurse

$i=1
Foreach ($f in $File)
{

   Copy-Item $f "E:\copyforbuild\"
   Rename-Item  -path "E:\Copyforbuild\"+"$f" -newname "CopyForbuild"+"$i"+".txt"
   $i = $i+1
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can rename file while copying in Copy-Item, just provide full path in both places:

```
copy-item c:\PST\1.config c:\PST\2.config
```

This will rename 1.config to 2.config. No need to call separate rename function.
Your code should now look something like this:

```
$File = Get-ChildItem -Path "V:\MyFolder\" -Filter CopyForbuild.bat -Recurse

$i=1
Foreach ($f in $File)
{
   Copy-Item $f.FullName ("E:\copyforbuild\" + $f.BaseName + $i +".txt")
   $i++
}
```

You can make it even shorter if use For loop:

```
$File = Get-ChildItem -Path "V:\MyFolder\" -Filter CopyForbuild.bat -Recurse

for($i = 0; $i -lt $File.Count; $i++)
{
   Copy-Item $File[$i].FullName ("E:\copyforbuild\" + $File[$i].BaseName + $i +".txt")
}
```

Or way shorter and wider if follow Richard's comment

Comment: Why not process everything one at a time (and remember variables get default values): `Get-ChildItem -Path V:\MyFolder -filt CoptForBuild.bat -rec | Copy-Item -dest {"E:\copyforbuild\" + $_.BaseName + ($i++) +".txt" }`. (Cmdlets with parameters that do not take type object, like `Copy-Item`'s destination, have an inbuilt for-each by using braces so there is no need for a loop to determine the destination.)

Comment: Buddy, It throws exception. "Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null." $File contains no items when specify "*.*"

Comment: $File = Get-ChildItem -Path "V:\MyFolder\\*.*" -Filter CopyForbuild.bat -Recurse

$i=1
Foreach ($f in $File)
{
    
   Copy-Item $f.FullName ("E:\copyforbuild\" + $f.BaseName + $i +".txt")
   $i++
}

Comment: When i am removing "*.*" , it works. (That's how richard also wrote
)

Comment: Buddy , can you update your answer by removing `*.*` so that i can mark it as answer

Comment: Done, you can also delete irrelevant comments